# Jquery click is bounded but not firing on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I got this piece of code

```
<div id="boxInformacion" class="alert-box success"><span>some text</span></div>
```

and in some .js file

```
var c = $('#boxInformacion');

c.on('click', function(){
    // some code
});

setTimeout(function(){
    c.click();
}, 9999);
```

(it's a little more complex the function inside click event, so it's simplified)

This code gets executed after an ajax call, on success.
The problem is that I click in the div but nothing happens.
I put the timeout only for checking that the bind is correct, and yes, after 9 secs the click is fired by javascript and is working.
The div `#boxInformacion` is the only one in all the `HTML` with that Id.

As the click in the timeout works fine, it seems that is some bug on the manual click.
I checked from the console and I'm clicking on the right place. 
What could I be missing?

I'm clicking on the green bar.

I also tried using `c.click(function(){ /* code */})` instead of `.on('click', function(){ /* code*/ })`

[image]

I'm using `jQuery 1.10.2`

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6nfUL/)

Comment: You could try `$(document).on('click','#boxInformacion', function() { ... }); `

Comment: Same result - nothing happens

Comment: Please add a fiddle. It's very hard to second guess what's happening here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your click handler is fine. The problem is your CSS:

```
z-index:-100;
```

Due to the negative z-index the click handler will not fire. Remove this and your click handler works.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6nfUL/2/)

Comment: YOU'RE A GENIOUS.  I'd never find that issue if it wasnt't by you. That code was added by a partner, anyway I didn't know that it makes the click not fired. Why is this ? Why the z-index cancel the click?

Comment: I guess it's because it's considered to be "behind" the document. It's not needed anyway.

Comment: yeah, definitely. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -2):

I tested out your code and it works perfectly.

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     var c = $('#boxInformacion');

     c.on('click', function(){
       alert(1);
     });

  })
 </script>
```

and this in the body tag

```
<div id="boxInformacion" class="alert-box success"><span>CLICK</span></div>
```

Comment: Did you check the fiddle ? Clearly there is not working

Comment: the problem is with the .alert-box in your css, removing the position attribute makes it work. the question is How come css hinder the jquery?